# Stack size in multiple vs projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stack, stack-size

Lets say I have a C++ Visual Studio solution with 5 projects A, B, C, D and E. The projects have set the /STACK linker option to:

- A = 4MB
- B = empty (by default 1MB)
- C = empty (by default 1MB)
- D = 16MB
- E = 25MB

All of them are built as separate DLLs with exposed functions. Project:

- A contains a function foo_a which calls foo_b (from B) and foo_c (from C)
- B contains the function foo_b which calls foo_d (from D) and foo_e (from E)

What will be the stack size if I would call function A.foo_a ? Will it be the same if I would call directly E.foo_e ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually started threads (with CreateThread) can get a custom size from the arguments of the function call, the main thread´s stack size is set accoring to informations from the EXE.

Your five DLLs don´t matter at all.
They can have a custom size set by the linker in their file header,
but the OS won´t do anything with it.

(The runtime stack size (on Windows) is per thread, not per file.)